# Problem dealing with OLS estimator

Tags: least-squares, matrix-inverse

I'm an econometrics student and I'm having a little trouble with lineal algebra.

I have seen that the OLS estimator, given the following regression in matrix form:
$$
y=X \beta+u
$$
Is:
$$
\hat{\beta}=\left(X^{\prime} X\right)^{-1} X^{\prime} y
$$
But, at the same time, using some matrix properties:
$$
(A . B)^{-1}=B^{-1} \cdot A^{-1}
$$
I'm arriving to the following result:
$$
X^{-1}\left(X^{\prime}\right)^{-1} X^{\prime} y=X^{-1} I_{n} y=X^{-1} y
$$
This isn't right and I know it, but where is the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your reasoning works only in the special case where $X$ is invertible (i.e. it's square and has full rank). In general, $X^{-1}$ doesn't exist. For example, the number of data points typically differs from the number of features, so $X$ isn't square.

Comment: Oh ok, i didn't check that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix property you use is only true when X is non-singular. Non-singular means that the determinant is non-zero. A matrix can only have a determinant if it is square. In least squares problems you will almost never have a square X matrix since you usually have more observations than explanatory variables. If your number of observations is less than or equal to the number of explanatory variables, then you should be using penalized regression instead of OLS.

Comment: Yeah, understood, thank you!